# Not using header files in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-construction

I'm creating a small program which consists of a few source files on my desktop (I'm not using Xcode) which I compile from the command line. Since everything is so tiny and small I would like to skip using header files and have everything in my .m file. It would like something like this:

```
Foo.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FooClass : NSObject {
}
- (void) fooFunction;

@end


@implementation FooClass

- (void) fooFunction {

     NSLog(@"Printing bar");

}

@end




Main.m

#include <stdlib.h>
#import "FooFunction.m"


int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{   

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog (@"Running....");

    FooFunction *foo = [[FooFunction alloc] init];
    [foo fooFunction];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;

}
```

When I try to compile this I get `ld duplicate symbol fooFunction blahblahblah for architecture x86_64`

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad idea to include implementation files like .m files (or .c/.cpp).  If you need to include a file, it should probably be .h.

By including Foo.m, you have two implementations of `FooClass` existing, which the linker doesn't like.  This is because an include is like a copy and paste of the file at that point.

In your example, the compiler compiles two files - main.m and Foo.m, and in both there is an `@implementation` section for `FooClass`.

You should have one implementation between all compiled files, but you can declare the interface any number of times, which is the reason we put the interface declaration in the header files.

By this logic, although it isn't the convention, technically you could put everything in a single main.m file and just compile that.  However for sanity's sake, once you have more code, you should break it up into class .h/.m files.

There is one other (bad)option for not using headers, where you add only the @interface section to the files that would include it, but again, I don't recommend this, because you will go through linker hell when you edit one of these copies and forget the other.  In your case, you just add the `FooClass` `@interface` section to the top of the main.m file.

Comment: So then would the solution be to place the interface code in the Main.m file? I appreciate your explanation, but I'm still not clear as to how to avoid using header files.

Comment: @Eric: Avoiding header files means having just one file called main.m.  However, if you don't include any header files, you won't be able to use any libraries/APIs or organize your code.  If you have multiple source files, you should be using header files.  If you have one main.m and that's all, then you don't have to.

Comment: I also added one case that I forgot and almost don't want to mention because it is a hack, but would work with your multiple .m files without needing .h files.